# Combine five sentences into one

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, syntax

> There is nothing better than strolling in the park, seeing playing kids and hearing birds’ chirping.

Is this sentence grammatically, syntactically meaningful sentence?

I want to say that, I stroll in the park. There I see some small kids. They play games. There are various birds in the park and their chirping is very melodious. I want to express that five lines in one sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good English. It is normal to make a list like this.

I'd make some minor adjustments "...seeing kids playing..." (I feel we observe the playing and not the kids) and "hearing birds chirping"  (with no apostrophe) since we have a little "subject-gerund" and we don't need a possessive.

Comment: I cannot understand your correction properly. Can you please write down the line once again?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add in extra elements to make it flow naturally.

> I stroll in the park and see the small kids playing games and I listen to the birds chirping very melodiously.

It does seem a bit contrived though and I would probably split it into two sentences.

> I stroll in the park and see the small kids playing games. While I am in the park I also listen to the birds chirping very melodiously.